# server.timeout is perfectly working on local but on production not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to set request timeout grater than default time in node js after creating server its working on local site but when it deployed its not working.Before all back-end execution it will send the error in  response.My code like this

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var http =    require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

server.timeout = 900000;

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the logic in setTimeout will be running after every less than 30 minutes, so YES the heroku server will be still awake.

[Will setTimeout use Heroku free dyno hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887833/will-settimeout-use-heroku-free-dyno-hours)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are proxying the request to your node app and that the proxy server has a shorter timeout window. The answer is to increase the timeout of the proxy server request.