# NodeJS Server Hosted on Heroku Shuts Down After Some Time

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am hosting a nodejs (express) server using socket.io on Heroku. After a certain amount of time, I will be unable to access the server from a client - the socket requests will not receive a response. However, once I reload the root web page, I am able to access it. Why is this the case?

Comment: does this happen locally or just when launched on heroku?

Comment: Do you have any logging on it at all?

Comment: Are you using free Dynos, or paid ones?

Comment: I'm using free Dynos - do I need to use paid ones in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I need to upgrade to paid (hobby at minimum) Dynos, otherwise the app will go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Actually there are lots of ways to prevent free dynos from sleeping. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646858/avoid-heroku-server-from-sleeping/40647411#40647411 for details.